# How to get a CNContact phone number(s) as string in Xamarin.ios?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am attempting to retrieve the names and phone number(s) of all contacts and show them into tableview in Xamarin.iOS. I have made it this far:

```
 var response = new List<ContactVm>();
            try
            {
                //We can specify the properties that we need to fetch from contacts  
                var keysToFetch = new[] {
            CNContactKey.PhoneNumbers, CNContactKey.GivenName, CNContactKey.FamilyName, CNContactKey.EmailAddresses
            };
                //Get the collections of containers  
                var containerId = new CNContactStore().DefaultContainerIdentifier;
                //Fetch the contacts from containers  
                using (var predicate = CNContact.GetPredicateForContactsInContainer(containerId))
                {
                    CNContact[] contactList;
                    using (var store = new CNContactStore())
                    {
                        contactList = store.GetUnifiedContacts(predicate, keysToFetch, out
                            var error);
                    }
                    //Assign the contact details to our view model objects  
                    response.AddRange(from item in contactList
                                      where item?.EmailAddresses != null
                                      select new ContactVm
                                      {
                                          PhoneNumbers =item.PhoneNumbers,
                                          GivenName = item.GivenName,
                                          FamilyName = item.FamilyName,
                                          EmailId = item.EmailAddresses.Select(m => m.Value.ToString()).ToList()
                                      });



                }


                BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    tblContact.Source = new CustomContactViewController(response);
                    tblContact.ReloadData();

                });
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
```

and this is my update cell method

```
 internal void updateCell(ContactVm contact)
        {
            try
            {

                lblName.Text = contact.GivenName;
                lblContact.Text = ((CNPhoneNumber)contact.PhoneNumbers[0]).StringValue;

                //var no = ((CNPhoneNumber)contact.PhoneNumbers[0]).StringValue;
                //NSString a = new NSString("");
                // var MobNumVar = ((CNPhoneNumber)contact.PhoneNumbers[0]).ValueForKey(new NSString("digits")).ToString();

                var c = (contact.PhoneNumbers[0] as CNPhoneNumber).StringValue;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }


        }
```

I would like to know how to retrieve JUST the phone number(s) as a string value(s) i.e. "XXXXXXXXXX". Basically, how to call for the digit(s) value. 
this line of code

```
lblContact.Text = ((CNPhoneNumber)contact.PhoneNumbers[0]).StringValue;
```

throw a run time exception as **specified cast is not valid**

Comment: Are you sure each `contact.PhoneNumbers[0]` has a value and it is not null? Add a breakpoint there to check and you can see what type of objects are in the contact.PhoneNumbers[].

Comment: yes I am sure contact.PhoneNumbers[0] has value. value is "{<CNLabeledValue: 0x2813d80c0: identifier=67B19668-E8E4-402E-B29F-4B1755A0A49F, label=_$!<Home>!$_, value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x2806fce80: stringValue=9********7, initialCountryCode=(null)>>}"

Comment: From the info you shared, the `PhoneNumbers` should be `contact.PhoneNumbers[1]`, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution. Here is my code if any one required.

```
CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber> numbers = 
  (Contacts.CNLabeledValue<Contacts.CNPhoneNumber>)contact.PhoneNumbers[0];
                CNPhoneNumber number = numbers.Value;
                string str = number.StringValue;
                lblContact.Text = str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exception is correct. First of all, you don't need any casts at all, contact.PhoneNumbers[0] will return you CNLabeledValue, so you just need to write it in next way

```
lblContact.Text = contact.PhoneNumbers[0].GetLabeledValue(CNLabelKey.Home).StringValue
//or
lblContact.Text = contact.PhoneNumbers[0].GetLabeledValue(CNLabelPhoneNumberKey.Mobile).StringValue
```

or you may try, but not sure if it works

```
contact.PhoneNumbers[0].Value.StringValue
```

Comment: Hi choper, I have tried all of your code that you suggested but its not working for me . error log is 
object' does not contain a definition for 'GetLabeledValue' and no accessible extension method 'GetLabeledValue' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)